# How to annotate succinctly object destructuring using FlowType and ES6?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Currently I am using the following code to annotate object destructuring (inline)

I would like to know if there a more succinct form, for example without using inline annotation.

Could you please provide me an example?

```js
// @flow
import React from 'react'
import moment from 'moment'
import IconWeather from '../../shared/icon/IconWeather'

const ForecastDay = ({ date, tempMin, tempMax, iconCode, weatherDescription }:{+date:Date, +tempMin: number, +tempMax: number, +iconCode:string, +weatherDescription:string }) => {
  const dateFormat = moment.unix(date).format('ddd, MMM D')
  const tempMinRounded = Math.round(tempMin)
  const tempMaxRounded = Math.round(tempMax)
  return (
    <div>
      <div>{dateFormat}</div>
      <div>
        <IconWeather code={iconCode} />
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>
          {tempMinRounded}&#176;
        </div>
        <div>
          {tempMaxRounded}&#176;
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        {weatherDescription}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
export default ForecastDay
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a possible solution separating the annotation on a separate type.

If you have a better solution, please report to me, I would like to learn more.

Code I am using:

```js
// @flow
import * as React from 'react'
import moment from 'moment'
import IconWeather from '../../shared/icon/IconWeather'

/* eslint-disable no-undef */
type PropsType = {
  date: number,
  +tempMin: number,
  +tempMax: number,
  +iconCode:number,
  +weatherDescription:string
}
/* eslint-enable no-undef */

const ForecastDay = ({ date, tempMin, tempMax, iconCode, weatherDescription }:PropsType) => {
  const dateFormat = moment.unix(date).format('ddd, MMM D')
  const tempMinRounded = Math.round(tempMin)
  const tempMaxRounded = Math.round(tempMax)
  return (
    <div>
      <div>{dateFormat}</div>
      <div>
        <IconWeather code={iconCode} />
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>
          {tempMinRounded}&#176;
        </div>
        <div>
          {tempMaxRounded}&#176;
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        {weatherDescription}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
export default ForecastDay
```